# Re-signing a ClickOnce manifest in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vsto, clickonce, visual-studio-2012

I have a [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) solution that has a postbuild event [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script that modifies the manifest file. After the manifest file is modified, I resign it using [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This all worked great in Visual Studio 2010, and now after upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 this no longer works.

I found some information on a Microsoft form that eluded to the fact that the encryption for Visual Studio 2012 manifest files has changed, and this is why resigning one that targets [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0 does not work. Upgrading the solution to .NET 4.5 is not an option as this program is for Excel 2010.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly confusing. I looked up the Visual Studio 2012 documentation and noticed that for `mage.exe` it referred to the [**Windows SDK for Windows 7**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). Interestingly, Mage is included with the Windows 8 SDK tools, but it is now in the folder `\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\` instead of just bin... So my post build events were pointing at the wrong SDK folder...

See *[Walkthrough: Manually Deploying a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx)* (MSDN).